# TaskCanceledException: Cancel or timeout?

Tags: c#, async-await, timeout, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I only want to use CancellationTokenSource for timeout and cancellation handling.

How to distinguish if a TaskCanceledException occured due to a timeout or due to manual cancellation?

Here is a simplified example. In the real program I neither know if CancellationTokenSource .CancelAfter() was used nor if someone called CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()

```
static CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            await SomeClass.DoSomething(cts.Token);
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
        {
            //How to find out if the exception occured due to timeout or a call to cts.Cancel()
        }
    });

    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);

        if (someCondition)
            cts.Cancel();
    }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public static async Task DoSomething(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        using (var innerCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(ct))
        {
            innerCts.CancelAfter(1000);

            //Simulate some operation
            await Task.Delay(10000, innerCts.Token);
        }
    }
}
```

thanks

Tom

Comment: Does it have an inner exception?

Comment: I believe it cancels it the same way as calling Cancel manually, therefore you cannot really differentiate it.

Comment: Couldn't one use `Task.Delay` with `Task.WhenAny` and cancel the linked token source created above if the returned task is the delay task?

Comment: `.CancelAfter()` does exactly what it says on the tin: it cancels. This is not a timeout and there is no difference with other methods of cancellation. If you want to differentiate, either use new tasks (per Ray) or make sure you have access to the `CancellationTokenSource` that is used for delayed cancels, use it *only* for delayed cancels, and check its `IsCancellationRequested` afterwards.

Comment: @Ray The often seen approach using Task.WhenAny() only makes the waiting "disapear" but it does not cancel the underlying operation

Comment: @JeroenMostert Checking CancellationTokenSource.IsCancelationRequested does not work for linked sources as they have IsCancellationRequested == true if any of them gets cancelled. Only way around that is to use an own CTS for the timeout handling

Comment: Well yeah. That's a separation of concerns thing: code that's "under" the top-level code has no need of knowing why the cancellation happened, just that it did. Otherwise cancellation would have to be extended with a mechanism to pass a reason/exception type, just so the bottom layer could propagate that back up again -- that gets complicated quickly. Only the code initiating the cancel knows why. (If the level where you produce the timeout is not the level handling the exception, it can catch the cancellation and throw a `TimeoutException` instead, but it still needs to know itself.)

Comment: @TomB Which is why I mentioned to cancel the CTS once you checked the returned task is the delayed one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK this is the most commonly used pattern:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    try
    {
        await SomeClass.DoSomething(cts.Token);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException) when (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // cts cancellation occurred
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        // Timeout occurred
    }
});
```

Another idea is to change the implementation of the `SomeClass.DoSomething` method, assuming that you are allowed to do it, so that in case of timeout it throws a [`TimeoutException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timeoutexception) instead of an `OperationCanceledException`.

```
public static async Task DoSomething(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    using var innerCts = new CancellationTokenSource(millisecondsDelay: 1000);
    using var linkedCts = CancellationTokenSource
        .CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken, innerCts.Token);

    try
    {
        // Simulate some operation
        await Task.Delay(10000, linkedCts.Token);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException) when (innerCts.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        throw new TimeoutException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to be the only way to create a CTS for the timeout only and keep track of it